# My code in c is giving wrong output

Tags: c

I wrote this code in c, to find the largest prime factor of number i, and it gives j=5102831, which is prime but not a factor of i.

The code seems write to me, so it feels like there is something wrong with the compiler.

So, someone please copy this code and check what output it's giving.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int prime (int);

int main()
{
    int i=600851475143,j;

    j=i-1;
   for ( ; ; j--)
        {
            if ((i%j) ==0)
                if(prime(j))
                    return (j);
            if (j==2)
                break;
        }
    return 0;
}

int prime (int j)
{
    int k;
    for(k=2; k<=j-1; k++)
        if((j%k)==0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", i);`.

Comment: `600851475143` cannot fit in `int` variable....max value is `2,147,483,647`

Comment: your prime computation is inefficient. And `600851475143` doesn't fit in 32-bit integer.

Comment: Please enable and deal with compiler warnings.

Comment: Your code doesn't output anything.

Comment: "so it feels like there is something wrong with the compiler" - this is almost *never* the case.  The problem is in your code, not the compiler.  Like others have pointed out, `600851475143` is not guaranteed to fit into an `int`.

Comment: What size is `int` on your platform?  On mine (Linux, amd64), I get `warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion` from the attempt to assign to `i` - perhaps you're missing `-Woverflow` from your compilation flags?  If that's your problem, it may help to use `unsigned long` instead.  Never ignore (or disable) warnings like that!

Comment: Some observations: you should put the initialisation and test of `j` in the loop control: `for (j=i-1;  j >= 2;  --j)`, and you can start from `sqrt(i)` rather than all the way from `i-1`: `for (j=(int)sqrt(i);  j >= 2;  --j)`.  You'll need to include `<math.h>` for the latter, of course.  Similarly, in `prime()`, you can terminate the loop earlier: `for(k=2;  k*k<=j;  ++k)`.

Comment: How mmany people have used the compiler?  How many have used your code?  Therefore, which one is probably wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
        if ((i%j) !=0)
                  ^^^
            if(prime(j))
                return (j);
```

Also take into account that 2 is a prime number.

Comment: looping to the number is highly inefficient. looping to sqrt(number)+1 is enough (and is sqrt(n) complexity)